# Best way to build member pages with EF and ASP.NET controls?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, crud

I'm trying to build a website that has a Member section, and I'm struggling to find a fast and efficient way to build the enduser pages, which will pull a user's data.

For example, the user's "my account" page.  They simply need to be able to view and edit the data.  Would you use the Entity Frameworks EntityDataSource control?  And bind it to a FormView, DetailsView, or ListView?  How do you allow automatic updates, and filter the view to always be the user's own record?

It seems like a lot of the data controls are geared towards dealing with multiple records.  Or am I just missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/) has scaffolding options that helps you build these sorts of views.  I prefer mvc these days as the designer generates most of what you need when you create views.  There is also a way to modify the templates since they are are T4 templates.

There is also [Dynamic Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488540.aspx) which can generate html dynamically from EF models.  I played around with this a bit and was extremely impressed with how much you get right out of the box.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't want to use ASP.NET MVC right now, as it will add one more variable to the equation.  As for Dynamic Data, it doesn't really apply to the situation.  Dynamic Data (I think) is better for building simple back-end administrative pages, not end-user pages.  Also, personally, I have found it very limited, with many "gotchas".